# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [OrderHistory] with [class java.lang.String]

Tags: testng, extentreports, testng-annotation-test

I am having issue with this error. it used to work fine earlier. then now i am learning on TestNG extentreports and Listeners. created those classes and all. now this error is bothering me.

Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [OrderHistory] with [class java.lang.String]. For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

public class SubmitOrderTest extends BaseTest {

```
//String productName="ZARA COAT 3";
@Test(dataProvider="getData",groups={"Purchase"})
public void submitOrder(HashMap<String,String> input) throws IOException {
        
      
    ProductCatalouge productCatalouge=landingpage.loginApplication(input.get("email"),input.get("password"));
    
    List<WebElement>products= productCatalouge.getProductList();
    productCatalouge.addToCart(input.get("product"));
    CartPage cartPage= productCatalouge.goToCartPage();
            
    Boolean match= cartPage.varifyProductsDisplay(input.get("product"));
    Assert.assertTrue(match);
    CheckOut checkout= cartPage.goToCheckout();
    checkout.selectCountry("India");
    ConfirmationPage confirmationPage=checkout.submitOrder();
    
   String confirmMessage=confirmationPage.confirmationmessage();
   Assert.assertTrue(confirmMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("THANKYOU FOR THE ORDER."));
    }

@Test(dependsOnMethods={"submitOrder"})
public void OrderHistory(String productName)
{
    ProductCatalouge productCatalouge=landingpage.loginApplication("shah.nira@gmail.com","Love123");
    OrderPage orderPage=productCatalouge.goToOrderPage();
    Assert.assertTrue(orderPage.varifyOrderDisplay(productName));
    
}
@DataProvider
public Object[][] getData() throws IOException
{
    List<HashMap<String,String>> data= getJasonDatatoMap(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//src//test//java//NikiAcedamy//FrameDesign//data//PurchaseOrder.json");

    return new Object[][] {{data.get(0)},{data.get(1)}};
}
```